# Averaging over a solid angle

Tags: geometry

How does one averages a function over a solid angle? I'm used to do this with conventional angles but it's the first time I come across this problem with a solid angle.

In my specific problem, the function is only dependent on the azimuthal angle, which should simplify the problem somewhat and the average is over $4\pi$ steradians, but a generic solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Similarly to a 2D angle, you integrate the function over the solid angle of interest and divide by the solid angle.  If it depended upon both $\theta$ and $\phi$ and you were interested in the whole sphere, you would do $\overline{f}=\frac{\int f(\theta,\phi)\cos(\theta)d\theta d\phi}{4\pi}$.  If your function does not depend upon $\theta$, that integral is 2 ($\cos\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$) and now you have a usual 2D style average.  So $\overline{f}=\frac{\int f(\phi) d\phi}{2\pi}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the equation posted on 3/14/2011 for averaging over the entire sphere was slightly incorrect.  The cos(θ) should be a sin(θ), assuming that θ=elevation from 0-π and ϕ=azimuth from 0-2π.  So the equation for the average over a full sphere would be:

$$\bar f=\frac{∫∫f(θ,ϕ)sin(θ)dθdϕ}{4π}$$

Removing the θ dependence produces a 2 (integral of sinθ from 0 to π) in the numerator, yielding the same result as posted above, i.e:

$$\bar f=\frac{∫f(ϕ)dϕ}{2π} $$